# Primefaces FileUpload not working in a Linux Server - working in a Windows Server

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, tomcat8

It is working perfectly in a Windows server deployment. And now I deployed to a Tomcat in a Linux Server and is not get the file upload working, i am unsure of what the issue is, any one got any ideas?

The file upload, triggers the upload window that allows a user to select a file, but from then onwards nothing happens, it should display a message to the user to say if successful or not, these do not appear.

Here is the JSF page :

`<p:fileUpload label="#{esp.chooseLabel}"cancelLabel="#{esp.cancelLabel}" uploadLabel="#{esp.uploadLabel}"invalidFileMessage="#{esp.invalidFileMessage}"multiple="false"fileLimit="1"invalidSizeMessage="#{esp.invalidSizeMessage}"listener="#{imageFileBean.handleUploadImage}"mode="advanced" sizeLimit="1000000000"rendered="#{not imageFileBean.hasImage()}"update="upload-pic-panel"allowTypes="/(.|/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" id="upload"/>`

The console has no errors or anything

Any Ideas? I'm using Tomcat 8.5.

Comment: What're the differences between the two environments?

Comment: Path seperation is a significant difference. The default upload size might be different for the Tomcat too. These Infos would help:
- Tomcat upload size configuration
- Path to wich the File is to be uploaded to
- Read/Write permissions on the upload path

Comment: I agree with @PascalP. most likely the default Tomcat upload size is not configurely correctly on the Linux server but is on the Windows server.  I think it defaults small like 1MB or something.

Comment: @BalusC, nothing in catalina.out.

Comment: @PascalP., maxPostSize="52428800" at server.xml. Where can I find the upload Path?

Comment: @Melloware, I tested with small file like 1k only and 0k also.

Comment: @WoAiNii, windows work and linux don't work. same deploy war file.